# How to return $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery and made a plugin for some in house work that basically builds URLs for our internal API. Anyways, I want to return $(this) and im not getting the right thing and im getting a createdocumentfragment error?

Plugin code:

```
$.get(base_url,{
    agenda_id:defaults.id,
    action:defaults.action+defaults.type,
    output:defaults.output
},function(html){
    defaults.callback(html);
});
```

That works fine, but i want to add return obj like so:

```
$.get(base_url,{
    agenda_id:defaults.id,
    action:defaults.action+defaults.type,
    output:defaults.output
},function(html){
    defaults.callback(html);
    return obj;
});
```

Obj is set at the start of my plugin and obj works fine throughout the plugin. It's set as `obj=$(this);`

In my script, which uses the plugin, I have:

```
$('#agenda-live-preview').agenda({action:'get',type:'agenda',id:window.location.href.split('/').pop(),callback:function(html){
    $(this).empty().append($(html).html());
}});
```

However, it doesn't work and returns:

```
Error: doc.createDocumentFragment is not a function
Source File: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js
Line: 4373
```

In the console error logs. Any ideas how to return $(this) AND run the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (finally) left a comment in your other question. :o) I'm pretty sure you need to do this in your plugin:

```
defaults.callback.call(this,html);
```

instead of:

```
defaults.callback(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to return the object to the original caller.

```
agenda = function(opts, callback) {
    $.get(base_url,{
        agenda_id:defaults.id,
        action:defaults.action+defaults.type,
        output:defaults.output
    },function(html){
        defaults.callback(html);
    });

    return obj;
}
```

I'm guessing the idea is to enable chaining, so that you can say something like

```
$('#id').agenda(opts).show();
```

or whatever.  Of course, this will execute just after the $.get is *issued* and not after it is completed, but this is normal and probably what you want.